# Format C -style comments in VS2015

Tags: c++, formatting, comments

In VS 2015, is there a way (native, preferred, but will consider plugins which are free for use) to nicely format C style comments? Word wrap, alignment of the stars, etc.

Currently, when I type /*, it auto-completes with */. But, when I press Enter, the stars do not line up:

```
/*
*/
```

Is there a way to have them align?

```
/*
 */
```

And, is there a way to have a leading * auto-inserted after Enter is pressed?

```
/*
 Want this line to start with a *, without having to type it.
 */
```

Comment: [ClangFormat](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html). Check it out and start using it. It's good.

Comment: Does not seem to work in VS2015... installed and restarted, but nothing appears to work.